# Cloud Computing terminology

Tags: cloud, cdn

Is the CDN serivce a part of the Cloud Computing conception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud computing is not a conception, it is a marketing label. As such it is able to cover any architecture involving at least two computers, one of them being owned by a big company.

Answer (score 0):

If by CDN you mean [Content Delivery|Distribution Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (as opposed to the Coin Dealer Newsletter or Certified Dialysis Nurse) then the answer is still probably "No".

Of course, Cloud Computing is in many ways still at the hand-waving stage where many concepts may be considered to be included.  But I think the core concept of Cloud Computing is having access to an externally managed service which delivers resources on demand.   Distributed computing may be a part of the infrastructure of that service but I don't think that means Cloud Computing encompasses CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. I would also say the IBM 1401 was too.

The "Cloud computing" thing is just a name for an architecture that has been used for a long time, but is now gaining ground in consumer markets ... so we give it a fancy name. Any dumb-terminal/fat server system is similar, we just use different protocols and other layers of abstraction.

I log into my personal cloud with X11 forwarding and Xen virtual machines all the time.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind "Cloud computing" is sort of network of virtualized computers that perform computation. Sort of Grid Computing but more general purpose. It more about computing, processing.

At the same time CDN is just storage. It could be in cloud. But it does not perform computation. So my answer is NO.

*[CDN]: Content Delivery Network